# Rails 4, No Method Error when attempting to access an objects attributes in jbuilder template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I am using jbuilder to build a json reponse. See below, my jbuilder template:

```
json.array! @items do |item|
    json.title                          item.title
    json.description                    item.description
    json.category                       item.categories.first.title
    json.price                          item.price / 100.0
    json.status                         item.status

    if !item.banned?
        json.published_date             item.published_date
        json.seller_name                item.seller.name
    end

    json.seller_latitude        item.seller.latitude.to_f
    json.seller_longtitude      item.seller.longtitude.to_f
end
```

I am able to access an object from the item.categories collection like so, with no problems:

`item.categories.first`

When I try to pull the title attribute from the returned category object from above I get this error in the browser:

`undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass`

I put a byebug statement just before this line in my jbuilder template:

`item.categories.first.title`

And in the byebug console I can access the title attribute no problem. See byebug console print out below:

```
Started GET "/items.json" for ::1 at 2016-07-16 13:59:45 -0400
Processing by ItemsController#index as JSON
  Item Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items"

[1, 10] in /Users/Macbook/projects/VSC/app/views/items/index.json.jbuilder
    1: 
    2: json.array! @items do |item|
    3:  json.title                          item.title
    4:  json.description                item.description
    5:  byebug
=>  6:  json.category                       item.categories.first.title
    7:  json.price                          item.price / 100.0
    8:  json.status                         item.status
    9: 
   10:  if !item.banned?
(byebug) item.categories.first.title
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "categories"."id" = "categorizations"."category_id" WHERE "categorizations"."item_id" = $1  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 1]]
"movies"
(byebug)
```

I'm stumped, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is the sql that is triggered when jbuilder renders the view:

```
Started GET "/items.json" for ::1 at 2016-07-16 14:24:29 -0400
Processing by ItemsController#index as JSON
  Item Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items"
  Category Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "categories"."id" = "categorizations"."category_id" WHERE "categorizations"."item_id" = $1  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 1]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "categories"."id" = "categorizations"."category_id" WHERE "categorizations"."item_id" = $1  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "categories"."id" = "categorizations"."category_id" WHERE "categorizations"."item_id" = $1  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 3]]
  CACHE (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "categories"."id" = "categorizations"."category_id" WHERE "categorizations"."item_id" = $1  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 4]]
  CACHE (3.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "categories"."id" = "categorizations"."category_id" WHERE "categorizations"."item_id" = $1  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 5]]
  CACHE (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "categories"."id" = "categorizations"."category_id" WHERE "categorizations"."item_id" = $1  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 6]]
  CACHE (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "categories"."id" = "categorizations"."category_id" WHERE "categorizations"."item_id" = $1  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 7]]
  CACHE (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "categories"."id" = "categorizations"."category_id" WHERE "categorizations"."item_id" = $1  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 8]]
  CACHE (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "categories"."id" = "categorizations"."category_id" WHERE "categorizations"."item_id" = $1  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 9]]
  CACHE (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "categories"."id" = "categorizations"."category_id" WHERE "categorizations"."item_id" = $1  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 10]]
  CACHE (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "categories"."id" = "categorizations"."category_id" WHERE "categorizations"."item_id" = $1  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 11]]
  Rendered items/index.json.jbuilder (317.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 329ms (ActiveRecord: 11.6ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass):
    2: json.array! @items do |item|
    3:  json.title                          item.title
    4:  json.description                item.description
    5:  json.category                       item.categories.first.title
    6:  json.price                          item.price / 100.0
    7:  json.status                         item.status
    8: 
  app/views/items/index.json.jbuilder:5:in `block in _app_views_items_index_json_jbuilder___331360250519835275_70269069934300'
  app/views/items/index.json.jbuilder:2:in `_app_views_items_index_json_jbuilder___331360250519835275_70269069934300'
```

Comment: Ok, can you check the SQL it is triggering when Jbuilder is rendering the view? That SQL will be the good debugging point to start

Comment: I am posted the SQL that is triggered when jbuilder is rendering the view, please have a look

Comment: Ok, fine. I can see now there are items with id *1* to *11* which has _categories_. Next item after *id 11* is breaking the code. Now, open the `rails console` and item which has `id` as `12` probably, and I am sure it has no categories associated with it. And that is causing the issue. So, you need to do some filtering to select only items which has categories.

Comment: solved! Thanks @ArupRakshit

Answer (score 0):

You see `item.categories.first` exists, it does mean that `another_item.categories.first` always exists with `another_item` is an `item` in the loop:

```
json.array! @items do |item|
  json.category item.categories.first.title
end
```

Please check this in console to find which items do not have any category:

`Item.all.find_all{ |item| item.categories.empty? }`